# jQuery UI-Slider no 'live' effect and CSS Styling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

Basically a couple of issues here as the ui-slider ucas points & grades that appear below are not 'live' per-say  I would like them to appear as the slider is used. So all the calculations are happening straight away, so as you slide they change, not when the user stops.

Also, How would I go about styling the bar so as the bar moves up the bit that has been slid will turn a certain colour.

For a live version: http://universitycompare.com

My jQuery for the slider's can be seen below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var slider1 = $("#slider").slider({
        max: 420,
        min: 0,
        step: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s2").html(ui.value);    
            $("#s2")
        },
        stop:Calculate
    });

    var slider2 = $("#slider2").slider({
        max: 420,
        min: 0,
        step: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s3").html(ui.value);    
            $("#s3")
        },
        stop:Calculate

    });

    var div = $('#s4'); //cache this object in a variable if you'll be using it multiple times
    slide: function Calculate(){
        var val1 = slider1.slider('option', 'value');
        var val2 = slider2.slider('option', 'value');

        var finalVal = (val1 + val2) / 2;
        //update the ui
            if (finalVal === 0) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('N / A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 20) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('N / A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 40) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('N / A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 60) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('N / A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 80) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('N / A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 100) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('N / A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 120) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('EEE');
            }

            if (finalVal === 140) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('DEE');
            }

            if (finalVal === 160) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('DDE');
            }

            if (finalVal === 180) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('DDD');
            }

            if (finalVal === 200) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('CDD');
            }

            if (finalVal === 220) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('CCD');
            }

            if (finalVal === 240) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('CCC');
            }

             if (finalVal === 260) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('BCC');
            }

             if (finalVal === 280) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('BBC');
            }

            if (finalVal === 300) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('BBB');
            }

            if (finalVal === 320) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('ABB');
            }

            if (finalVal === 340) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('AAB');
            }

            if (finalVal === 360) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('AAA');
            }

            if (finalVal === 380) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('A*AA');
            }

            if (finalVal === 400) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('A*A*A');
            }

            if (finalVal === 420) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
               //if finalVal does equal 220
               div.text('A*A*A*');
            }

    }
});
```

The CSS for the slider is here also, but doesn't seem to change colour:

```
/* Slider
----------------------------------*/
.ui-slider { position: relative; text-align: left; background-color:#ffdd4e; height:7px; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 1.2em; height: 1.2em; cursor: default; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range { position: absolute; z-index: 1; font-size: .7em; display: block; border: 0; background-position: 0 0; }

.ui-slider-horizontal { height: 7px; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle { top: -.5em; margin-left: -.6em; background-color:#ffdd4e; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range { top: 0; height: 100%; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min { left: 0; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max { right: 0; }

.ui-widget-header { background-color:#0071bc !important; height:8px !important; left:1px !important; top:1px !important; position:absolute !important; }
```

Comment: Did you fix your stop/change issue? Your link seems to indicate this.

Comment: @j08691 - I did start editing it, but It is still not styled nor do the values change as it is slid up and down. It is only when the slider stops.

Comment: Have you tried adding a call to your calculate function inside the slider's change event?

Comment: @j08691 - where would I place the call? Sorry, I am new to jQuery unfortunately and I am learning a little slower than hoped!

Comment: What is the line `$("#s2")` and `$("#s3")` supposed to do in your change functions?

Comment: @j08691 it changes the value based on where the tab is on the slider.

Comment: Try changing the change function to call the calculate function like `change: function(event, ui) {$("#s3").html(ui.value);$("#s2");Calculate();}`

Comment: @j08691 - nope! Still isn't working, any idea why? Just want it to change when dragged!

Comment: @j08691 similar to how wonga.com works: https://www.wonga.com/

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with the problem?

Comment: @j08691 - How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/UN8AZ/24/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UN8AZ/25/ ?

Comment: @j08691 - yes it is indeed! what was changed so I know for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UN8AZ/25/)**.

To both your sliders I added a call to your calculate function to the slider's slide event.

```
slide: Calculate,
```

Update:

To show the slider values, use this instead:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    Calculate();
    $("#s2").html(ui.value);
},
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UN8AZ/26/)**

Note that in this fiddle I changed your CSS to make the values visible (e.g. you had white on white).

Comment: Cannot thankyou enough, the Average A Levels now change as you slider, but is there a way to change the Numeric totals to the right of the sliders to change with also?

Comment: Thank you very much @j08691 - definitely appreciate your help and your patience! Thank you very much buddy! Actually made me understand more as well! :)